# How to use MultiDatesPicker v1.6.1 in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

[MultiDatesPicker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/multidatespickr/files/latest/download) is a little plugin that enables jQuery UI calendar to manage multiple dates with the following features, Pick multiple dates not in sequence, Define a maximum number of pick-able dates and Define unavailable dates. How to use in Wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

As this is a jQuery plugin you cannot use it directly as a plugin in Wordpress. For this you need to create a custom plugin and then you can include the same in your Wordpress.

For the custom plugin to be created, you can use "[Hello Dolly](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hello-dolly/)" plugin which will be readily available and you can edit that plugin as per the requirement.

These docs will help you creating the "[custom plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)" in Wordpress.

This is the good and proper method generally I follows for creating a plugin in Wordpress. Hope this helps.